# Migrate Postgres 9.4.5 to 11.1

Tags: postgresql

Looking for a way to migrate Postgres 9.4.5 to the latest version 11.1 with **minimum possible downtime**.

What we have is:

- Database size - 1.2TB, total # of rows > 4B
- (primary) Postgres 9.4.5
  running on AWS (self-managed), this is a primary instance.
- (secondary standby) Secondary instance replicated using Streaming
  Replication
- Regular disk snapshots and WAL archiving
- Daily logical
  backups (`pg_dump`)

We tested two options so far: `pg_dumpall/pg_restore` and `pg_upgrade`, both options work ok but take more than 48hr to finish.

According to the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#UPGRADING-VIA-REPLICATION there is also Logical Replication option. However, it is my understanding that 9.4 only has a Logical Decoding (not the replication). So this option is not available in our case, correct?

**Are there any other options to migrate to v11 with a minimum downtime as possible?**

Comment: `pg_upgrade` with the `--link` option should be quite fast

Comment: we considered "link"  option but if something goes wrong during upgrade we have to restore db from the backups.

Comment: it can be done via pglogical
check from Replication between PostgreSQL 9.4 and PostgreSQL 11
https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/04/04/replication-between-postgresql-versions-using-logical-replication/

Comment: This might be better asked on sister site DBA.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I believe that pg_upgrade is your best option. You don't mention anything specifically that should present a problem. Logical backups are still supported.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I have successfully upgraded 9.4.20 to 11.5 without any issues.

But can we just rely on belief? In my case application have good test coverage and I have reviwed release notes for breaking changes.

In general for any significant part of system I prefer multi-step upgrades from major to major releases.

For 9.4.x to 11.6 (by today on AWS) it like 4 steps (at least in development):
 * 9.5.20
 * 9.6.16
 * 10.11
 * 11.6

Every step should be performed with respect of certain Release Notes and warnings during application testing.

Except pg_upgrade it is possible to use replication.

Comment: That absolutely **not** necessary in Postgres. You can upgrade from 9.5.x to 11.x directly without problems

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you absolutely right ) And I have done this from 9.4.20 to 11.5
But before I have reviewed "migration" for every release/major release note.
Actually it may require attention to indexes and some extensions.